# async task in static class

Tags: android, class, static, android-asynctask, android-fragments

i'm using actionbar sherlock/fragments with my app

my problem is that i need to call a async task to run in the fragment which is a static class

the complier is complaining about "No enclosing instance of type KeywordSearch is accessible"

i've thought of moving the async class out and create it's own class, but there are too many variables declared in my KeywordSearch class that is used in the async task

how can i execute the async task without crashing?

my list view class(fragment):

```
public static class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView list_list;
    private LazyAdapter adp_list;

    private KeywordSearch.SearchTask run;
    //run.execute();

    //new SearchTask().execute();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);            
    }
    @Override   
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        if(!RTN_REQ.equals("SSDR") && data_got){
        adp_list.imageLoader.stopThread();
            }
        list_list.setAdapter(null);
        if(data_got)
        ImageLoader.clearCache(true,true);       
        super.onDestroy();      
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        /*
        if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            list_list.setNumColumns(2);
        }else if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            list_list.setNumColumns(3);
        }
        */
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
        adp_list = new LazyAdapter(getActivity(),list_data, 0);
        run = new SearchTask();
        list_list = (ListView) v.findViewById (R.id.list);
        if(list_data != null){

            list_list.setAdapter(adp_list);
            list_list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {               
                    String[] FINAL = list_data[arg2].split("##");
                    final Intent d = new Intent();
                    d.putExtra("DATA",FINAL[0]);
                    d.setClass(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Details.class);   
                    startActivity(d);
                    return false;
                    }
            });           
            list_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3)
                {
                    if(!eno_act){
                        String[] FINAL = list_data[arg2].split("##");
                        final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(FINAL[1]));                 
                        startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                        String[] FINAL = list_data[arg2].split("##");
                        level = 1;
                        level_filter = FINAL[2];
                        run.execute();  //this is where it crashes!!




                    }

                }
            });     
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

and my SearchTask class:

```
 class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //....to long to show..
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
        //....to long to show..
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {
        //....to long to show..
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        //....to long to show..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass those variables of your KeyWordSearch class in constructor of async task class

for example

```
int foo;   

public SearchTask(int foo)  //your variables here
{
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

For passing data example

//in your async task you can do that in doInBackground or any other method.
  Let foo is your string array

```
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
 Intent i = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class)
 b.putExtraStringArray("myStringArray", foo);
 i.putExtras(b);
```

// Receive this array in your activity as

```
 String[] myArray =  this.getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("myStringArray"); //this should be done after executing asyncTask class.
```

Comment: you mean if i move my async task out? so this is how i'll pass all my vars to the async class right?

Comment: yes this way you can pass variables and use the them anywhere in your asyncTask class.

Comment: and execute async class as  `new SearchTask(your varaibles here).execute();`

Comment: what if i want to pass stuff back?

Comment: like: Sting foo;  -> new SearchTask(foo).execute(); -> System.out.println(foo);

Comment: if you want to pass stuff back use intents. They are easy to use.

Comment: pass context of your activity and then `Toast.makeToast(context, "msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); but you can show them only in onPostExcecute(); method.

Comment: Last thing, if i want to return a String[] or whatever, what should i do? please give me an example(code)....

Comment: you mean after executing aysncTask class you want to return String[] to your activity?

Comment: exactly! i need the new String[] value... when i do it all in one class, i don't have to worry about that(make my String[] global), now it's in separate class...

Comment: checkout the answer. just use bundle and intents for this.

Comment: i've add your answer to my code, but the string returns null, any ideas?; i've add the bundle b ..... part in my onPostExecute part in async task; and the placed the getintent part right after i call the async task; am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: i guess you are getting null because after executing your asyncTask class you immediately getting the string array in next line. Note that asynctask runs on different thread than your main UI thread so your asyncTask thread should be finished before getting that string  array.